# Java regex matches only if matching is checked

Tags: java, regex, conditional-statements

Inside of a class I have a pattern `private Pattern lossWer = Pattern.compile("^\\d+ \\d+ (\\d+).*")`. One of the functions looks like this:

```
public double[] getWer(){
    double[] wer = new double[someStrings.size()];
    Matcher m;
    for(int i = 0; i < wer.length; i++){
        m = lossWer.matcher(someStrings.get(i));
        wer[i] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    }
    return wer;
}
```

Calling this fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`. When I change it to this, though, it works:

```
public double[] getWer(){
    double[] wer = new double[someStrings.size()];
    Matcher m;
    for(int i = 0; i < wer.length; i++){
        m = lossWer.matcher(someStrings.get(i));
        if(!m.matches())
            ;
        wer[i] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    }
    return wer;
}
```

Of course my application doesn't just use a blank semi-colon for that line, but I'm illustrating that the line here does nothing but allows the program to proceed without error. Why are lines matched without errors in the second example but not in the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [group()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) without first calling either [find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) or [matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). That's how regexes work. First you create a pattern, then a matcher, then you either find() instances of the regex or check if it matches().

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for the IllegalStateException

> The explicit state of a matcher is initially undefined; attempting to
>   query any part of it before a successful match will cause an
>   IllegalStateException to be thrown. The explicit state of a matcher is
>   recomputed by every match operation.

This combined with Ryan's answer should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Until you call `m.matches()` you haven't tested the regex so there are no groups.

You say in that line, test against the regex. If there are no matches do nothing, then you continue on to check the group(1) of the match (and since there was a match with a group it works).

It would be best to change:

```
    if(!m.matches())
        ;
    wer[i] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
```

To:

```
    if(m.matches())
        wer[i] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
```

Or use `!m.matches()` to return an error or something. Your choice :)